# how to solve NoSuchElementException with nextLine()?

Tags: java, file-io, input, arraylist

I have been writing this code but it gives me error. based on my understanding, they looks good though.

The text file is:

```
2
Galaxy
Samsung phone
2.99
iPhone
Apple phone
3.99
```

The code is:

```
public class IO {

    static final String FILE_LOCATION = "C:\\IO.dat";
    static ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();

    public static void main(String[]args){

    File name = new File(FILE_LOCATION);

        if(name.canRead())
            System.out.println("Your file is ready to use");

        Scanner inFile;
        PrintStream ps;
        try{
            inFile = new Scanner(name);

            int partNum; 
            String product; 
            String company;
            double price;

            partNum = inFile.nextInt();
            inFile.nextLine();


            for(int i=0; i<2 ; i++){

                product = inFile.nextLine();
                System.out.println(product);

                company = inFile.nextLine();
                System.out.println(company);

                price = inFile.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(price);

                inFile.nextLine();

                productList.add(new Product(product, company, price));
             }

            inFile.close();

            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                System.out.println("File is not good for use");
            }

            for(int i=0; i<productList.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(productList.get(0));
                }
    }
}
```

Product class

```
public class Product {
    String name;
    String company;
    double price;

    public Product(String name, String company, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.company = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + company + " " + price;
    }
}
```

When I ask for print from ArrayList, it gives me like `Galaxy Galaxy 2.99` rather than `Galaxy Samsung phone, 2.99`.

Comment: how is your Product class, toString() method implemented?

Comment: You're forgetting to go over a Variable. You have 4 in the file Galaxy Samsung phone 2.99. in the loop you're looping 3, so product will be galaxy, company samsung, skipping phone since you're looking for double, and 2.99.

Comment: toString() returns name + " "+company + " "+price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement will throw a `NoSuchElementException` at the end of the second iteration

```
inFile.nextLine();
```

if there are no more lines remaining. You could do

```
if (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
    inFile.nextLine();
}
```

Also in the `Product` class

```
this.company = name;
```

should be

```
this.company = company;
```

Comment: Your suggestion totally makes sense and worked but it still gives me,
Your file is ready to use
Galaxy Galaxy 2.99
iPhone iPhone 3.99

I think I need to use next or nextLine carefully

Comment: Post your Product class - I suspect you are assigning the company name to the product field

Comment: package IO;

public class Product {
 String name;
 String company;
 double price;
 
 public Product(String name, String company, double price){
   this.name=name;
   this.company=name;
   this.price=price;
  }
 public String toString(){
  return name +" " + company+ " "+ price;
 }
}

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to edit and add my product class but it said I have some error-formatted code and do not know what it talked about , So I updated here

Comment: Bingo! youre assigning the name to the company field in `Product`

Comment: Thank you so much, I cannot thank you enough. I will work harder, yeah thanks.

Comment: Absolutely. I am happy to mark it as helpful answer. and this entire post

Comment: I have added the `Product` class into the question

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring a "PrintStream" object if you're not using it?
Well, the Scanner class sometimes shows problems to read numbers and strings with the same Scanner Object.
You could create one to read numbers - `obj.nextInt()` - and another to read the Strings - `obj2.nextLine()` - =)

Comment: Oh, PrintStream is for next stage for me to test my understadning but since the previous one(Scanner) did not work for me, I left it as comments first. lol. Thank you Gabriel.